# How to find the value of this integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Can someone please explain how

$$\tfrac{1}{2\pi a^2} \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-(n-1)i\theta}[1+\tfrac{e^{2i \theta}}{a^2}+\tfrac{e^{4i \theta}}{a^4}+\cdots] \, d\theta =0 $$

when $n$ is even ?

Comment: Are you sure you want $\pi$ in most of the exponents?  I don't think the integral will be zero now.

Comment: yes, this is the exact complete integral. And it says that this is 0 when n is even and not when n is odd

Comment: @AmanMittal, we know, $e^{2r\pi}=1$ for all integer $r\implies \frac{e^{2r\pi i}}{a^{2r}}=\frac1{a^{2r}}$

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice that the other powers of $e$ lack $\theta$ in the exponent - referring to lab's next comment

Comment: @Michael, I am talking about the multiplier of $e^{-(n-1)i\theta}$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the entire thing inside the bracket wont affect the total integra i guess.. so how does n=even makes it zero. ?

Comment: @AmanMittal, I didn't say that. I was trying to check the convergence of the multiplier.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Very sorry,The question i wrote was incorrect.

Comment: @Michael Very sorry,The question i wrote was incorrect.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Now you have terms that involve $\exp(i(1-n)\theta)$, $\exp(i(3-n)\theta$ and so on.  The other answers below explain why the integral of each of them is zero, and why, if $n$ is odd, one of the integrals will not be zero.

Comment: @Michael I am unable to see which term will remain non-zero for odd  values of n. for even all are coming zero as expected

Comment: If $n=5$, then the term with $\exp(i(5-n)\theta)$ will remain nonzero because then $5-n=0$ and you are integrating $\exp(0)=1$.

Comment: oh !! Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

As $$\int e^{mx}dx= \begin{cases} \frac{e^{mx}}m+C_1 &\mbox{if } m\ne0 \\
x+C_2 & \mbox{if }m=0 \end{cases} $$ where $C_1,C_2$ are arbitrary constants of indefinite integration

If $n\ne1,$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-(n-1)i\theta} d\theta  =\left(\frac{e^{-(n-1)\theta i}}{-(n-1) i}+C\right)_0^{2\pi} =\frac{e^{-2(n-1)\pi  i}-1}{n i}$$

Now use [Euler Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

Can you manage for $n=1$?

Comment: But in this case, the integral will be zero for both even and odd values of n ?

Comment: @AmanMittal, I am editing

Comment: Except $n=1$.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @AmanMittal, clearly,  any integer $n\ne1$ will satisfy this

Comment: but the problem i am solving says the integral becomes zero only when n is even and not when n is odd. am i missing out on something

Comment: @AmanMittal, could you follow my method? May I know, the source ?

Comment: yes i follow your results well. This integral is a part of complex analysis problem from JN Sharma. Let me update my question to present the complete integral. may be that will help

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

When $k\ne0$,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac1{ik}\left(e^{ik2\pi}-1\right)
$$
When $k$ is an integer, this is $0$.

When $k=0$, $e^{ik\theta}=1$ so the integral is $2\pi$.

In any case, when $n$ is even $k=-(n-1)$ is odd, and not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

It works if $n$ is any integer except $1$.

Picture what the graph of $\theta\mapsto e^{-(n-1)i\theta}$ looks like: as $\theta$ moves along a line from $0$ to $2\pi$, the value $e^{-(n-1)i\theta}$ goes around the unit circle in the complex plane at a uniform rate.  It goes around $n-1$ times.  So its average location is exactly at the center of the circle.  The one exception, $n=1$, makes $n-1=0$, so it winds around the circle $0$ times.

**The above answers the question that was originally posted, before further editing.**  But the answer to the amended question uses the same idea.